# What does it mean "a piece of schlock"?

Tags: expressions, idioms, yiddish

What does *a piece of schlock* mean in the following phrase?

> "You aren't in this game to write a piece of schlock."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some context would be helpful but:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlock

> **Schlock** is an English word of Yiddish origin meaning "something cheap,
>   shoddy, or inferior

The speaker is telling the subject not to write something low quality.